# Cross origin blocking despite subdomain exists in policy

Tags: ajax, apache, cors

Hello I am trying to use cross origin from a subdomain (app.example.com) to www.example.com. When I try to execute the ajax I receive this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://app.example.com/. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://app.edentalbook.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I dont understand how I should use it..In my apache conf file I have those lines in order to enable cross origing policy:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://app.example.com"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
```

My ajax call:

```
        $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url:'http://www.example.com/index.php?logout',
                        crossDomain: true, 
                        dataType: "json",
                        xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: false
                        },
                         success: function(data){
                             loginPresta(email,password,companyName);
                         if(data == 'ok') {
                         }
                     },
                     error:function(data){  

                     }
                });
```

Comment: What is the url of your ajax page?

Comment: Dusan I am trying to call the logout function of prestashop with the ajax call that I edited in the question. I have though some questions: in Access-Control-Allow-Origin i have to write the address of the domain that requests permission right? Do I have to insert something in the target .htaccess also? Plus I dont know if it is relevant but i am using linux ubuntu with plesk.

Comment: I am a bit confused with your domain names, but yes, you need to have  the address of the domain that requests permission in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You can test with having `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, but you should also google for your `Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`, that one is strange.